# Suspend keyword causing errror while inserting in room database kotin(android)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting the following error when inserting in room database
`>

> error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
> kotlin .coroutines .Continuation<? super kotlin .Unit> continuation);
> `

***This is my DAO***

```
@Dao
interface FavDishDao {
    @Insert
    fun insertFavDishDetails(favDish: FavDish)
    @Query("SELECT * FROM FAV_DISHES_TABLE ORDER BY ID")
    fun getAllDishesList(): Flow<List<FavDish>>
}
```

**build.gradle files**

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
 }

android {
namespace 'pro.shivanshtariyal.recipeapp'
compileSdk 33

defaultConfig {
applicationId "pro.shivanshtariyal.recipeapp"
minSdk 21
targetSdk 33
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"

testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"     }

buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
    }
compileOptions {
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
packagingOptions{
exclude 'META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module'
   }
kotlinOptions {
jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
buildFeatures {
viewBinding true
  } }

dependencies {

...
def room_version='2.2.6'
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1' }

 `plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
 }`
```

I tried to remove the suspend keyword, the app was build but when I tried to save the data I got the following error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: pro.shivanshtariyal.recipeapp, PID: 5274
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:267)
```

FavDish file

```
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "fav_dishes_table")
data class FavDish(
    @ColumnInfo val image: String,
    @ColumnInfo (name = "image_source") val imageSource: String, // Local or Online
    @ColumnInfo val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo val type: String,
    @ColumnInfo val category: String,
    @ColumnInfo val ingredients: String,
    // Specifies the name of the column in the table if you want it to be different from the name of the member variable.
    @ColumnInfo(name = "cooking_time") val cookingTime: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "instructions") val directionToCook: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "favorite_dish") var favoriteDish: Boolean = false,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0
)
```

Comment: Can we see your FavDish class?

Comment: @Tenfour04 
'import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
@ Entity(tableName = "fav_dishes_table")
data class FavDish(
    @ ColumnInfo val image: String,
    @ ColumnInfo (name = "image_source") val imageSource: String,
    @ ColumnInfo val title: String,
    
    @  ColumnInfo val category: String,
    @ ColumnInfo val ingredients: String,
    ... 
    @ ColumnInfo(name = "instructions") val directionToCook: String,
    @ PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0
)' sorry I dont know how to format there are 9 columns

Comment: You can update the question to include this information.

Comment: I added the withcContext(Dispatchers.IO) in the viewModel and now its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because you are trying to write the database from the Main/UI thread. You must do it from another thread to avoid blocking the UI.

To fix this, you must create a [coroutine scope](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines) and insert to the database from there.

If you are in `Fragment` or `Activity`, use the following pattern:

```kotlin
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                insertFavDishDetails(favDish)
            }
        }
```

If you are in a ViewModel do the following:

```kotlin
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                insertFavDishDetails(favDish)
            }
        }
```

Comment: But preferably they would just mark the function `suspend` in the Entity class so they don't have to worry about dispatchers. OP said that's what they originally were trying to do but were getting a different error.